# Don't quite understand the mechanism of Dependancy Injection in Struts2 XWork

Tags: java, struts2, dependency-injection, xwork

I'm new to IOC and learning from source code of Struts2 framework currently. 
Through learning, I've got some basic understanding of the framework like how `ActionInvocation` handlers interceptors etc.

But when I was trying to figure out the mysterious (to me at least) Dependency Injection part,  I got completely lost.

The inject mechanism specified in package `com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject` is hard to comprehend. How exactly does the `ContainerImpl.inject(Object)` do all the work?
Or, where should I start in order to understand DI?

Comment: S2 uses an old (old!), hacked version of Guice for its DI. Personally I'd recommend starting to understand DI implementations elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I found [this](https://github.com/google/guice) resource useful. For others who like to dig old, very old user guide can download [Guice 1.0 User's Guide.pdf](http://google.github.io/guice/user-docs/Guice-1.0-Users-Guide.pdf). As Dave mentioned

> S2 uses an old (old!), hacked version of Guice for its DI.

So, you can use this page as a starting point for [Dependency Injection](http://struts.apache.org/docs/dependency-injection.html) with Struts2.

P.S.:

About `ContainerImpl.inject(Object)`

> Injects dependencies into the fields and methods of an existing object.

It's not mysterious because Guice like Spring autowires a bean. Spring like Guice can use annotations to wire object dependencies.